# Trying to Reproduce This Phonetically Spelled Accented Word

Tags: typography, accents

I am trying to replicate:

[image]

But I am unable to do it.

MWE (two different attempts)---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\begin{document}
\noindent\textbf{Mount Ar\'-a-rat}\\[10pt]
\textbf{Mount Ar\' -a-rat}
\end{document}
```

with output:

[image]

Comment: What about just `\textbf{Mount Ar'-a-rat}`? I would guess that the character after the r is supposed to be an apostrophe which you can input using simply `'`.

Comment: @JasperHabicht The accent mark, for me, ends up looking more like a comma that way.

Comment: Well, this is how an apostrophe looks like. But I don't know anything about the way this is supposed to be typeset. If you want to type an isolated acute accent, you need to type `\'{}`, but I am not sure whether this is typographically corrent in this context.

Comment: That stress mark looks more like a prime, and is equivalent visually to the transliteration of the cyrillic soft sign.  One way to input it is `$'$`, although that doesn't become bold automatically with `\textbf`.  A cyrillic transliteration is implemented in `amsfonts` as `\cprime`, but I'm not sure that will readily boldify.  I'll try to look it up.  (Laptop is misbehaving at the moment, so can't easily test.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you; this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In phonetic transcriptions the tonic accent is usually a straight quote. I provide also a slanted one (with a kerned acute accent over nothing).

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\tonic}{\makebox[0.15em]{\'{}}}

\begin{document}

Mount Ar\tonic-a-rat

Mount Ar\textquotesingle-a-rat

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use, for example, the `bm` package and the `\acute` symbol in the following manner:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\noindent \textbf{Mount Ar\bm{$\acute{}$}-a-rat} 
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]